# ¿Cómo hacer un <button> que traduzca un <p> cuantas veces quiera?

Tags: javascript, html

Por medio de Javascript hice un botón con la función de traducir un párrafo de Inglés a Español, no sé si lo hice de la forma correcta.

El error que tengo es que este botón solo me traduce el párrafo una sola vez y necesito que traduzca de Español a Inglés también.

```js
nombre = prompt("Ingresa tu nombre", "Nombre");
/*document.write("bienvenido "+nombre+" usted luce en este lugar");*/
function mifuncion() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Bienvenido " + nombre + ". usted luce en este lugar";
}
/*boton para traducir el parrafo*/
function mifunciondos() {
  document.getElementById("poema").innerHTML = "ENAMORADO \n\Dos joyas son dos árboles, muy cerca. \n\
    Siento la brisa que rodea nuestros brazos. Dos mezclan las sombras.El aire Dos besos Dos abrazos Ser verde, marrón \n\
    Enamorado.";
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article id="article1">
    <h2>ARTICLE ONE</h2><br><br>
    <p id="btnbien">Preciona el boton de bienvenida</p>
    <button onclick="mifuncion()">clickme</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
  </article>
  <article id="article2">
    <h2>ARTICLE TWO</h2><br><br>
    <!--Este es el párrafo q quiero que se traduzca de ingles a español y viceversa cuantas veces de click-->
    <P id="poema">
      <strong>IN LOVE.</strong><br>Two jewells are two trees<br> Close each other <br>I feel the breeze Around ours arms <br>Two mix the shadows
      <br>in the air<br> Two kiss<br> Two embrace<br> To be Green, brown<br> In love.
    </P>
    <!--boton para traducir-->
    <button onclick="mifunciondos()">Traducir</button>
  </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías simplemente ocultar la parte en inglés y mostrar la parte en español al presionar el botón, de la siguiente manera:

```html
`<html>  
<body>
<section>
  <article id="article1">
    <h2>ARTICLE ONE</h2><br><br>
      <p id="btnbien">Preciona el boton de bienvenida</p>
      <button onclick="mifuncion()">clickme</button>
      <p id="demo"></p>
  </article>
      <article id="article2">
        <h2>ARTICLE TWO</h2><br><br>
<!--Este es el párrafo q quiero que se traduzca de ingles a español y viceversa cuantas veces de click-->
        <P id="poema">
        <strong>IN LOVE.</strong><br>Two jewells are two trees<br> Close each 
         other <br>I feel the breeze Around ours arms <br>Two mix the shadows
        <br>in the air<br> Two kiss<br> Two embrace<br> To be Green, brown<br> 
         In love.
        </P>
        <P id="poemaTrac" style="display:none">
        <strong>ENAMORADO</strong><br>Dos joyas son dos árboles, muy cerca.<br> 
        </P>
                          <!--boton para traducir-->
               <button onclick="mifunciondos()">Traducir</button>
            </article>
         </section>
       <script src="js/javascript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>`
```

En Javascript:

```
function mifunciondos(){document.getElementById("poema").style.display='none' ? 'block' : 'none'; document.getElementById("poemaTrac").style.display='block' ? 'none' : 'block'; }
```

De esta manera se ocultará el texto en inglés, mostrando en español y viceversa. Espero haberte ayudado :)  (Le falta más al de español, pero eso tú puedes agregar el texto ;) )

Comment: Hice el código que me dijiste pero no ejecuta nada, debe faltar algo.